# How to return only top level items in TFS query

Tags: tfs, tfs-query

Using the TFS web interface, I need to compose a query that will return all of the Features in which any User Story or Bug has the Release field set to a particular release, which I can do (see the screen shot) but the trick is:  how do I return ONLY the Features and not the child work items as well?

[image]

I have tried various permutations of this query to get the results I want.  For example, I tired selecting "Return selected link type = Parent" but this had zero effect on the results returned. Any ideas?

After having struggled with this for quite a while I am forced to conclude that this is a failing in TFS. There is no way to return only top level results when the query depends on properties of the linked PBI's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by starain-MSFT and Andy-MSFT in comments above, it is not possible to generate a query which returns ONLY top level items based on conditions within the children of those top level items *in the web interface alone*, which is what I needed.  It is apparently possible to pull a query using a REST API but then, you would not be able to build a dashboard widget using the parsed results.

Answer (score 1):

Just try to set the query as below:

Type of query : Work items and direct links

***Filters for top level work items:***

```
    Work item type = Feature 
And Area Path Under ADSuite\
```

***Filters for linked work items :***

```
    Work item type in User Story, Bug 
And RELEASE <> Release 07   #or RELEASE Not Under Release 07
```

***Filter options***

```
Only return items that do not have matching links
```

***Types of links***

```
Return links of any type
```

---

We can only use the opposite condition to list the features without child work items. We need to list all the opposite conditions...  But seems it's difficult to set the condition combination. In my opinion, if you just need to query out the features, you can export the query result (which with the child work items) to excel, them filter out the features. That should be an easy way.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the attempted answer.  I have configured the query as you have outlined and while it does only return top level items, it is returning some features that do not have stories in Release 07.  In fact some of the features returned we haven't worked on for over a year.

Comment: I have further discovered that the Features returned do not include ANY Features with Release 07 stories and bugs.

Comment: @zeeple We can only use the opposite condition to list the features without child work items. We need to list all the opposite conditions...  But seems it's difficult to set the condition combination. In my opinion, if you just need to query out the features, you can export the query result (which with the child work items) to excel, them filter out the features. That should be an easy way.

Comment: thanks for the comment! Having to export anything to excel (which I do not have on my Mac anyway) means that the TFS web interface is lacking the feature I need, which is to return top level items whose children meet a specific condition (not opposite at all!).  I need the query to work for the purpose of having widgets on various dashboards, but even then, I think that the query feature is broken.

Comment: @zeeple You can't do it through query directly, you may do it through WorkItem REST API and filter the work items grammatically.